# Exception ao ler arquivo excel usando apache poi

Tags: java, exceção, xls

Estou tentando ler um arquivo Excel (XLS), usando a API Apache Poi, e estou tomando a *exception*:

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid header signature; read 0x0020000A000DFEFF, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:140)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:104)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem.<init>(POIFSFileSystem.java:128)
    at br.com.sfera.utility.LerXLS.lerArquivoXls(LerXLS.java:32)
    at br.com.sfera.utility.LerXLS.main(LerXLS.java:21)
```

**Segue abaixo o método java que faz a leitura do arquivo xls.**

```
public void lerArquivoXls(String arquivoXls)
    {
        try {
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(arquivoXls));

            POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileSystem);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator linhas = sheet.rowIterator();
            while(linhas.hasNext()){
                HSSFRow linha = (HSSFRow) linhas.next();
                Iterator celulas = linha.cellIterator();
                while(celulas.hasNext()){
                    HSSFCell celula = (HSSFCell) celulas.next();
                    if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC==celula.getCellType()){
                        //celula numerica
                        System.out.println(celula.getNumericCellValue()+" - ");
                    }
                    else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING==celula.getCellType()){
                        //celula de string
                        System.out.println(celula.getStringCellValue() + " - ");
                    }else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN==celula.getCellType()){
                        //celula booleana
                        System.out.println(celula.getBooleanCellValue() + " - ");
                    }else if(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK==celula.getCellType()){
                        //celula em branco
                        System.out.println(" == VAZIO == ");
                    }else{
                        //celula desconhecida
                        System.out.println(" == FORMATO DESCONHECIDO == ");
                    }
                }
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar, a como evitar esse problema, ou qual a causa de como evitar essa *exception* e conseguir ler o arquivo XLS sem problemas?

Comment: O arquivo abre no excel ? Porque a linha  `Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document` indica que está com problemas no cabeçalho. Tente salvar novamente se for o caso ou converter para uma versão mais nova do excel `xlsx` de de volta para `xls`.

Comment: @Kyllopardiun sim o documento abre no Excel, fiz os teste e salvando em uma versão do .xls mesmo (2003), ele conseguiu ler o arquivo normalmente. O problema é que o arquivo que o meu programa vai ser é auto gerado por um outro programa que realizar a exportação desde arquivo. Com isso não posso pedir para o usuário abrir e salvar o arquivo novamente.

Comment: Sei que parece improvável, mas tentou usar o `XSSFWorkbook()` ?

Comment: @Kyllopardiun então fiz um outro metodo usando o XSSFWorkbook() para ler arquivox *.xlsx, e funciona beleza. O meu sistema precisa ler arquivos *.xlsx, .csv e .xls. E assim, como estes são gerados por outro sistema, o probelma que encontrei no .xls é que parece não estar salvo no padrão. Quando abri e salvei novamente manualmente o arquivo, meu programa leu ele e processou normalmente, sem erro nenhum.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método abaixo para selecionar o arquivo. Aqui funcionou:

```
JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.showDialog(chooser, "Selecionar");
        File arquivo = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(arquivo));
```